# Do we 'declare' jQuery or we simply use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was asked in an interview that how do you *'declare'* jQuery? He did not mean a jQuery variable or a `$(func())`. In case you find this question weird, please do not penalize me for this as I'm enquiring just cause I was asked. :)

Comment: Perhaps he meant how one would include jQuery? As in, how to use a `<script>` tag to reference it?

Comment: @Interrobang: Thats what I told him. You do not have to declare. You simple add the latest jquery.js file and call doc ready function. He did not seem to be convinced. Such questions make one lose confidence when one is new to something :)

Comment: I agree. That almost sounds like an HR guy that was given a list of screening questions to ask that he didn't really understand. You're in the right, carry on!

Comment: I would say both. 'var ctr = $("#txLogin")' but also directly, depends on use.

Comment: @Rohan - It sounds like you gave the correct answer (noting though that you don't have to call doc ready). If he didn't seem convinced either he was looking for an answer so obscure that nobody here knows it either, or Interrobang is correct that he didn't understand what he was asking. Or both. I've had interviews where a non-technical person just read technical questions off the page.

Comment: Thanks to you all, my confidence is back, but still im not confident about getting through. :P :)

Answer (score 15):

You don't "declare" jQuery, you just include the file within a script tag:

```
<script src="/locationof/jQuery.js"></script>
```

If you look in the [jQuery source](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js) it appends itself to `window.$` and `window.jQuery` when it runs as the source code is in a self-executing anonymous function.

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
   // rest of source here

   // Expose jQuery to the global object
   window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
})(window);
```

Comment: +1: If you interpret the question literally, this is probably as good an answer as any.

Comment: +1: This would be an excellent answer in an interview if the interviewer actually knew what they were asking - in which case they perhaps wouldn't have asked this at all unless it was intended as a trick question. (Unfortunately if the interviewer was a manager or HR person who had been handed a list of technical questions then your guess is as good as mine as to what answer they might be happy with.)

Answer (score 2):

We don't "declare" jQuery, we just add "reference" to the file where is this library in. For example:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps he meant how to include it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess he was assuming that you say using a `$` sign